# problems with tikz and arabi package

Tags: tikz-pgf, theorems, nodes, arabic

I have some problems and I hope you can help me.

When I put a `tikzpicture` and use the `arabi` package, the picture is not displayed in the `dvi` 
or `pdf` file, and this without a single error.

I have a solution for that (which I don't like), I have to put the TikZ picture inside 
an english language environment, like this :

```
\begine{otherlanguage}{english}
\begin{tikzpicture}
...
...
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{otherlanguage}
```

it is a boring solution and not suitable if I want to create environments like boxed theorems, etc.

Here is a sample :

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass{report}


\usepackage[Latin1, utf8, cp1256]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1, OT1, LAE]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english, arabic]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%% Indian to Arabic Numerotations %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\textLR{\arabic{enumi}}-}
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\alph{enumii})}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumii}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\textLR{\arabic{equation}}}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\textLR{\arabic{section}} -}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\textLR{\arabic{page}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\section{المتتاليات العددية}

\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=red, fill=blue!20, very thick,
    rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle} =[draw=red, fill=blue!20, text=black, rectangle, rounded corners]
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
\begin{minipage}{.89\textwidth}
\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}     

لتكن $f$ دالة مستمرة على المجال $[a,b]$ و قابلة للإشتقاق على $]a,b[$, 
حيث $f(a)=f(b)$.
إذن, يوجد عدد حقيقي $c \in ]a,b[$ حيث 
$$
f(c)=0
$$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, left=10pt] at (box.north east) {\AR{نظـريـة}};
\node[fancytitle, rounded corners] at (box.east) {$\clubsuit$};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{otherlanguage}

\begin{center}
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,rounded corners=8pt]
(0,0) -- (0,2) -- (1,3.25) -- (2,2) -- (2,0) -- (0,2) -- (2,2) -- (0,0) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{center}


\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

you can try to compile this code with pdflatex without

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}

\end{otherlanguage}

in the last picture. this picture isn't displayed in the output pdf file.

Comment: ps: there is no enumerate environnement.

Comment: yes, it work well for this example. But each time i must use 
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
tikz picture ...
\end{otherlanguage}


and inside the tikz picture there is another 

\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
Arabic text ....
\end{otherlanguage}

Comment: Like i said, this is not suitable if i want to creat a good looking  
boxed environnements like theorems, lemmas... etc

Comment: yes, (\end{enumerate}) is removed now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be due to an incompatibility between TikZ and babel with the `arabic` option. It can be rectified reasonably easily, though.

To make TikZ work in a document that's using babel with the `arabic` option, the `tikzpicture` environment needs to be in an `english` environment. To automatically switch to `english`, you can put

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\selectlanguage{english}}
```

in your preamble.

To switch to `arabic` for the text within the tikzpicture, you can put

```
\tikzset{font=\selectlanguage{arabic}}
```

into your preamble. The contents of `font` are executed at the start of each node.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, arabic]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\tikzset{font=\selectlanguage{arabic}}


\begin{document}

\section{المتتاليات العددية}

\tikzset{
    mybox/.style={
        draw=red, fill=blue!20, very thick,
        rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=10pt, inner ysep=20pt
    },
    fancytitle/.style={
            draw=red, fill=blue!20, text=black, rectangle, rounded corners
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [mybox] (box){%
\begin{minipage}{.89\textwidth}

لتكن $f$ دالة مستمرة على المجال $[a,b]$ و قابلة للإشتقاق على $]a,b[$, 
حيث $f(a)=f(b)$.
إذن, يوجد عدد حقيقي $c \in ]a,b[$ حيث 
$$
f^\prime(c)=0.
$$
\end{minipage}
};
\node[fancytitle, left=10pt] at (box.north east) {\AR{نظـريـة}};
\node[fancytitle, rounded corners] at (box.east) {$\clubsuit$};
\end{tikzpicture}%

 للإشتقاق

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much Jake.
I will see what i can do with it and come with a new qustions :)

Comment: @singular: Pleasure! If the answer helps, you can upvote it by clicking the triangle next to the answer, and if it solves your problem, you can also mark the question as answered by clicking the tick mark.